# How do I use input from `selectizeInput` to filter a list of options and then `updateSelectizeInput`?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, observers, selectize.js

**BACKGROUND:**

I have a large list of stock symbols, 27,000 rows, that I would like to be choices in a `selectizeInput()` on a shinyApp. Since the list is large I am using `server = T` in `updateSelectizeInput()`.

**AIM:**

I would like the options list to not load/render until a user starts typing a string into `selectizeInput()`, so that I can return all symbols that start with that letter, to reduce loading all 27,000 rows in the input. I would like `input$ticker` to be what is observed and then what triggers the filtering code logic. How can i achieve this without using a specific button?

Shown below is

1. *intended output*, but with a button to produce the behavior instead of the user being in the text box. This is along the lines of what I would like, but does not automatically start searchign when I type in the box and has bad code smell to me.
2. *current logic*, using `input$ticker` in an observer to trigger selection of df and populate `updateSelectize()` with new choices, but is failing and the app is evaluating too soon?\
3. *trying to load choices once*, using upload button only doesn't work

**REPREX:**

1.

```
library(shiny)
tickers <- rep(rownames(mtcars), 850)
ui <- {
    renderUI(
        shiny::fluidRow(
            bs4Dash::box(
                title = shiny::selectizeInput(
                    inputId = "ticker",
                    label = "Ticker:",
                    choices = NULL,
                    selected = "AAPL",
                    options = list(
                        placeholder = "e.g AAPL",
                        create = TRUE,
                        maxOptions = 50L
                    )
                ),
                actionButton(
                    inputId = "update",
                    label = "UPDATE NOW"
                ),
                id = "tickerBox",
                closable = F,
                maximizable = F,
                width = 12,
                height = "250px",
                solidHeader = FALSE,
                collapsible = F
            )
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session){
    choice <-  reactive(
        tickers[startsWith(tickers$symbol, input$ticker), ]
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$update, {    
        updateSelectizeInput(
            session = session,
            label = "Ticker:",
            inputId ="ticker",
            choices = choice(),
            server = TRUE
        )   
    })
}
shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

2. 

```
# REPREX for selectize, glitches and `input$ticker` observer causes loop gltich?
library(shiny)
tickers <- rep(rownames(mtcars), 850)
ui <- {
    renderUI(
        shiny::fluidRow(
            bs4Dash::box(
                title = shiny::selectizeInput(
                    inputId = "ticker",
                    label = "Ticker:",
                    choices = NULL,
                    selected = "AAPL",
                    options = list(
                        placeholder = "e.g AAPL",
                        create = TRUE,
                        maxOptions = 50L
                    )
                ),
                actionButton(
                    inputId = "update",
                    label = "UPDATE NOW"
                ),
                id = "tickerBox",
                closable = F,
                maximizable = F,
                width = 12,
                height = "250px",
                solidHeader = FALSE,
                collapsible = F
            )
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    
    # updateSelectizeInput(
    #     session = session,
    #     label = "Ticker:",
    #     inputId ="ticker",
    #     choices = tickers,
    #     server = TRUE
    # )
    
    
    observeEvent(input$ticker, {   
        
    choices <- tickers[startsWith(tickers$symbol, input$ticker), ]
        
        updateSelectizeInput(
            session = session,
            label = "Ticker:",
            inputId ="ticker",
            choices = choices,
            server = TRUE
        )   
    })
    
    
}
shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

3. 

```
# REPREX for selectize
library(shiny)
tickers <- rep(rownames(mtcars), 850)
ui <- {
    renderUI(
        shiny::fluidRow(
            bs4Dash::box(
                title = shiny::selectizeInput(
                    inputId = "ticker",
                    label = "Ticker:",
                    choices = NULL,
                    selected = "AAPL",
                    options = list(
                        placeholder = "e.g AAPL",
                        create = TRUE,
                        maxOptions = 50L
                    )
                ),
                actionButton(
                    inputId = "update",
                    label = "UPDATE NOW"
                ),
                id = "tickerBox",
                closable = F,
                maximizable = F,
                width = 12,
                height = "250px",
                solidHeader = FALSE,
                collapsible = F
            )
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session){
    # One call to try and load ticker df
    observeEvent(input$update, {    
        updateSelectizeInput(
            session = session,
            label = "Ticker:",
            inputId ="ticker",
            choices = ticker,
            server = TRUE
        )   
    })
    
    
}
shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

SEE SIMILAR POSTS:
[SO POST 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264119/updating-selection-of-server-side-selectize-input-with-1000-choices-fails/60343776#60343776), [SO POST 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432553/how-to-make-related-server-side-selectize-ui-elements-in-r-shiny-application), [SO POST 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71228067/r-shiny-selectizeinput-not-working-with-updateselectizeinput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `selectizeInput` doesn't accept a df and must be an atomic vector. When I used `tickers[[1]]`, the issue seemed to be solved, and the list would no longer flash.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about something like this?

```
library(shiny)

tickers <- rep(rownames(mtcars), 850)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML(
        'document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
          Shiny.setInputValue("key_pressed", e.key);
        })'
      )
      )
    ),
  fluidRow(
    column(2, selectizeInput("select", "Select", choices = "")),
    column(1, actionButton("btn", "Search"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    req(input$key_pressed)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "select", choices = tickers[startsWith(tickers, input$key_pressed)], server = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Basically I think it is not possible to just use the words which are putted to the `selectInput` and we need separate `input`. I think that `selectInput` is truthy (`isTruthy()`) only after some option was chosen (and it can't be `""` of course), so we can't use anything which is putted as a word to the `selectInput` box before some option is actually chosen. I'm not sure, but if I'm right, it is necessary to have separate `input` for what you want.

However, if we could assume that:

- User will use only one letter to get the options to choose

Then we can use `"keydown"` event ([keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event)). Now the user doesn't need to put anything to the `selectInput` box, she/he can just use a key in the keyboards, like `C` (letter size does matter here, because we are using `startsWith()`) and then push "Search" button (but of course this letter can still be put to the `selectInput` box to mimic what you tried to achieve). We could even imagine solution without the button, but I'm afraid in most use-cases it will be not recommended, I mean if user can interact with the app using keyboard not only to choose the options, but also for other purposes, then we would recompute new options everytime user uses key in the keyboard for - well - nothing.

Comment: Hmmm...the functionality is not necessarily what is intended. It seems to not show a list of possible options. I would like just like how YAHOO FINANCE can start to suggest options when you type things in or like may dropdowns... @gss